# Converting value of DateField in vaadin

Tags: java, date, converters, vaadin, datefield

I'm working with the Vaadin Framework at the moment. I want to convert the string in my `DateField` to `Date`. So I have two classes, one is the view and the other should contain the values which I save with data binding.

This is the DateField in the view:

```
timestart = new DateField("");
timestart.setId("timestart");
timestart.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
timestart.setValue(new Date());
timestart.setResolution(Resolution.MINUTE);
timestart.setConverter( XXX ); // Here i don't know what to do
layout.addComponent(timestart, 3, 2);
```

In the same class the data binding:

```
binder.bind(timestart, "timestart");
//This part is working
```

And in my other class:

```
private Date timestart;
```

I want to save this `timestart` in a database, so i need a formatted value like above `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` but when I do it without  `timestart.setConverter` I am getting a date like `Wed Jul 16 11:11:00 CEST 2014`.

How should I do this ?

Comment: WHat is the database type of this field/column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the Date in your bean class. Not in your View code.

```
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
private Date timestart;

public ConstructorOfYourClass{
    timestart = new Date(); //Default date
    //Your prefered date format
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"); 

} 
//... other Code ...


//Getter method of your Date
public String getdateFormat(){
return dateFormat.format(timestart);
}
```

Comment: Additional Information: 
You need two getters in your bean class. One of them should return the non formatted value. otherwise the binder will not work.