# How to extract the date from a DateField into different formats?

Tags: java, date, vaadin, datefield

I'm currently trying to use two [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) [`DateField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html) instances to create an interval between two dates.

I'd like to extract the dates picked to a format similar to **2016-04-11**. Time and timezone isn't necessary in my case. I'm only interested in the dates.

If I use getValue() I get a string that is formatted like this: **Mon Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2016**. I'm unsure how to use getConvertedValue(), but currently it returns the same thing as getValue().

[image: DateField and the return from getValue()]

I have set the DateFormat to **"yyyy-MM-dd"**. This doesn't seem to affect the return value of the get-function though.

I've also tried converting the return value into a Date() (Java-class), but this changes the dates in some weird manor and they never match up to the original.

**Main question:** How do I extract the date from a DateField to a "yyyy-MM-dd"-format?

Comment: You can use SimpleDateFormat class to format your date

Comment: There is a Grid/Table in your screenshot. Maybe there is a problem, maybe you can post your code where you use the DateField's value.

Comment: The grid/table doesn't cause any issues that I'm aware of. I looked at this problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24733370/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the DateField's value is a java.util.Date and not a java.lang.String (https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-datefield.html). If you want to format that Date, you can use the SimpleDateFormat (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Somehow I knew it was a date but never saved it as such. I made it harder for myself by converting it to a string and trying to parse it that way. Anyways, I'm stupid... Thanks!